# How to retrieve info about tile compression which geopackege file uses?

Tags: gdal, geopackage

Is there any way to retrieve info about tile compression (JPEG/PNG, PNG, etc.) which geopackege file uses?
I have tried a gdalinfo command, but it does not provide this type of information.

Answer (score 3):

Only way to get that information is to read all the tiles. Gdalinfo gives common information about the whole raster layer but the layer may be a mixture of PNG and JPEG tiles. By the GeoPackage definition

> Images of multiple MIME types MAY be stored in given table. For
> example, in a tiles table, image/png format tiles COULD be used for
> transparency where there is no data on the tile edges, and image/jpeg
> format tiles COULD be used for storage efficiency where there is image
> data for all pixels. Images of multiple bit depths of the same MIME
> type MAY also be stored in a given table, for example image/png tiles
> in both 8 and 24 bit depths.

PNG and JPEG tiles are always allowed. It is also possible to save tiles as WebP but in this case there must be a row in gpkg_extensions table to tell that a certain table may have WebP tiles. Such table may still contain also PNG and JPEG tiles.

Comment: Thank you for your valued answer. After some googling I have found end solution for me.

Answer (score 3):

The GPKG file does not store this information globally, instead any tile can be in a different format. You can try to determine the type of the data in a tile by comparing its first bytes against known "[magic bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)".

GPKG is a SQLite database, so you can run queries against the data with an SQLite client.

Here is an example that tries to guess the image data types using this approach:

```
SELECT
    count(*) FILTER (
        WHERE hex(tile_data) LIKE '89504E470D0A1A0A%'
    ) AS png
    , count(*) FILTER (
        WHERE hex(tile_data ) LIKE 'FFD8FFDB%'
        OR hex(tile_data) LIKE 'FFD8FFEE%'
    ) AS jpeg
    , count(*) FILTER (
        WHERE hex(tile_data) LIKE '52494646%'
    ) AS webp
from table_name;
```

| png | jpeg | webp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 81 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Nice idea! I wonder if should use `hex(left(tile_data,4))` to avoid the overhead of converting each whole tile? (I don't have SQL on the machine I'm writing this from to test.)

Comment: Idea is great, but this syntax didn't work for me, as it is stated at https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter#emulate-count, count(*) needs special treatment and second syntax stated there: COUNT(CASE WHEN <condition> THEN 1 END) worked for me.

Comment: My Geopackage has another (JFIF) magic byte for jpeg, so I must add 2 other magic bytes from your wikipedia link to make it work

Answer (score 2):

Based on [user30184's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/30184/user30184) [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/417982/how-to-retrieve-info-about-tile-compression-which-geopackege-file-uses/418006#answer-417989), I have found this final solution for my question (Tested on Ubuntu 18.04):

```
sudo apt install sqlite3
sqlite3 gepackage_name.gpkg "SELECT * FROM 'table_name';" | tr -cd "[:print:]" | less
```

- it shows string parts of all images in a given table in the database, and in case of png files, it shows PNG after an 8 signs sequence like this 1|8|0|0|
- in case of JPG, after the 8 signs sequence it shows nothing
- for reliable using it could be more polished (how to distinguish jpeg and webp, png bit depth, and so on), but for my case it is enough
- I used [this tutorial](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-dump/) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38833090/how-to-extract-text-portion-of-a-binary-file-in-linux-bash)

Based on [bugmenot123's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/51035/bugmenot123) [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/417982/how-to-retrieve-info-about-tile-compression-which-geopackege-file-uses/418006#answer-418010) and my comments there, the final one line solution to reliably count png, jpeg and webp tiles (in this order) was this:

```
sqlite3 geopackage_name.gpkg "SELECT count(CASE WHEN hex(tile_data) LIKE '89504E470D0A1A0A%' THEN 1 END) AS png , count(CASE WHEN (hex(tile_data ) LIKE 'FFD8FFDB%' OR hex(tile_data) LIKE 'FFD8FFEE%' OR hex(tile_data) LIKE 'FFD8FFE000104A4649460001%' OR hex(tile_data) LIKE 'FFD8FFE1%') THEN 1 END) AS jpeg , count(CASE WHEN hex(tile_data) LIKE '52494646%' THEN 1 END) AS webp from 'table_name';"
```